# Right way of accessing elements in an array of matrices defined using typedef in C

Tags: c

I defined a matrix structure in C using

```
typedef double mymatrix[30][30][10];
```

so now I define an array of them;

```
mymatrix AA[10];
```

now I tried to access, for a given matrix, the element (i,j,k), so I tried it for AA[5] using

```
AA[5][i][j][k] = 234.0;
```

is this the right way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the first index will be for the final declared variable.

If you:

```
printf("%d\n", &AA[1][0][0][0] - &AA[0][0][0][0]);
```

you should see 9000, or the number of elements in `mymatrix`.

Comment: Amardeep knows all! Good answer!

Comment: Thanks for the props but I continue to learn far more on SO than I can ever give back.